# Lazy loaded component does not update NGXS state

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular9

Ive started playing around with the new lazy loaded components in angular 9. I've got a stateful component using NGXS whose state is lazy loaded in a module near the component but once the component renders, the store is not updated with the new state.

**Feature module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forFeature([PurchaseState]),
    SharedModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    GridModule,
    PurchasesApiModule,
    SidePanelCoreModule
  ],
  declarations: [PurchaseDetailsPageComponent, PurchaseDetailsFormComponent, PurchaseDetailsAllotmentListComponent],
})
export class PurchaseDetailsModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('PURCHASE CONSTRUCTED')
  }
}
```

**Dynamic Component Loader**

```
  async getComponent(key: string) {
    const lazyComp = await import('@pe/purchase-details').then(c => c.PurchaseDetailsPageComponent);
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(lazyComp);
    this._component = this.content.createComponent(factory, null, this.injector);
  }
```

Things like the `GridModule` (which is only declared here) works alright, but im guessing the providers part of the module loading isnt being run?

Has anyone come across something like this?

I've tried including a module declaration for the state inside the component .ts file described in this [article](https://brianflove.com/2019/12/13/lazy-load-angular-v9-components/) but no dice :(

Answer (score 1):

So i was able to cobble together a solution after looking at how the angular router lazy loads modules.

I manage a cache of configs in an app level service and dynamically load things using this guy.

Happy to hear better solutions :)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lazy',
  templateUrl: './app-lazy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-lazy.component.scss'],
})
export class StatefulLazyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('content', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) content: ViewContainerRef;
  _lazyLoadSub: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    private compiler: Compiler,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const config  = {
      component: import('@pe/purchase-details').then(c => c.PurchaseDetailsPageComponent),
      module: import('@pe/purchase-details').then(m => m.PurchaseDetailsModule)
    };

    this._lazyLoadSub = combineLatest([
      this.getComponentObs(config.component),
      this.getModuleFactory(config.module)
      ]).subscribe(data => {
      const [compFactory, moduleFactory] = data;
      const module = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
      const component = this.content.createComponent(compFactory, null, this.injector);
      // Module and component are loaded can now do stuff with them
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this._lazyLoadSub) {
      this._lazyLoadSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  getComponentObs(promise: Promise<Type<any>>): Observable<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    return from(promise).pipe(mergeMap(comp => of(this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(comp))));
  }

  getModuleFactory(promise: Promise<Type<any>>): Observable<NgModuleFactory<any>> {
      return from(promise).pipe(mergeMap(t => from(this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(t))));
  }
}
```